# Is there a way to prevent index chunk from being updated by build process?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I have an app with asynchronous routes. It has routes intended to be used by regular users and a route to be used by admins only.

My problem arises from the fact that **index** chunk's hash changes every time there are changes in the app. It's expected behaviour, but it could be improved.

You see, it's inefficient, because if, say, I modify **admin** route component (intended to be used only by a small group of people) every user of my app has to download a new **index** chunk and it's a lot of KBs.

I understand why it happens. Since **index** chunk stores links to other chunks, whenever a chunk changes it's hash, **index** chunk must update its link map and change too.

**Here's build output (only relevant part)**

```
dist/js/index.b712bd3c.js                                     170.80 KiB
dist/js/admin.7f057e6f.js                                     34.17 KiB      
dist/js/user.0573741f.js                                      50.43 KiB
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to create some kind of **linker** chunk that stores the link map. For it to work the file must not have a hash and not be cached by browsers. So that whenever **admin** component changes only **linker** and **admin** chunk change.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `optimization.chunkIds` to `deterministic`? From [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationchunkids).

Comment: @User28, hey! I feel like there's a solution there. Need to investigate. Thanks!